# Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/crossSpawn'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarn

No se por que al ejecutar yarn start en mi proyecto de react no me deja verlo y solo me aparece :
lo uncio que hice es hacer una modificarcion en el src en coponents solo acomode de mejor forma los componentes y con eso ya no me funciona yarn start

```
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.10
warning ..\..\..\..\package.json: No license field
$ react-scripts start
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/crossSpawn'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\alanu\Documents\curso-react\Mis-ProyectosReact\aj-services\node_modules\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\alanu\Documents\curso-react\Mis-ProyectosReact\aj-services\node_modules\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js:18:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\alanu\\Documents\\curso-react\\Mis-ProyectosReact\\aj-services\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\bin\\react-scripts.js'
  ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Podría intentar remover su carpeta de `node_modules` y el archivo yarn.lock.

Después hacer `yarn` or `yarn install`